# .NET C# insert into SQLite > 1 million records in one batch

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to insert over 1 million entries in a SQLite database from C# code. If I do it one by one, it takes forever.  The insert statement is the same just with different parameters.  Was wondering if there is something like in Java `PreparedStatement st.addBatch(sql)`.  Also I am using the Entity Framework so wondered if it had any way of doing batch inserts as well. If not, then any other way will work as long as I can do it under reasonable amount of time.

I have tried to do it using transactions what seemed to work but wondering if there is any other proper way of doing it.  Also having this in Entity Framework would be the best for me.

This is what I have so far to get it to work:

```
SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand("insert into Entrys(ID,KeyEntry,Password) values(@id,@key,@pass)", con);
com.Parameters.Add("@id", DbType.Int64);
com.Parameters.Add("@key", DbType.Int64);
com.Parameters.Add("@pass", DbType.Int64);
com.Prepare();
SQLiteTransaction tr = con.BeginTransaction();
com.Transaction = tr;

int limit = 1000000;
for(int i=1;i<limit;i++)
{
    com.Parameters[0].Value = 1;
    com.Parameters[1].Value = i;
    com.Parameters[2].Value = i;

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

tr.Commit();
con.Close()
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at [Performing Batch Operations Using DataAdapters (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx) yet?

Comment: This code actually inserts 999,999 rows.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right kind of database for the right kind of task ?

Comment: I would be very leery of dealing with chunks of data this big unless you're sure the system has plenty of memory floating around to execute the command.

Comment: Thanks.  Transactions seem to work well, just wondered if there are others ways to handle it.  On Some of the comments:

Comment: records are very small so 1 mil of statements will not exceed 20MB, memory is not a concern.  Also, there were some concerns of my DB chose?  I have one single threaded application so though  that SQlite is a good chose what seem to be pretty robust, 0 cofig.  Do you see any issues with it?